# Deploying Node Express on AWS Recommendations

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have a node.js server I would like to deploy to AWS. My main site is example.com while the node server is on api.example.com

I am only using one EC2 instance (no load balancing) because I am only building an MVP and don't want to make things complicated.

I used Amazon Certificate Manager to register my domain name and I need to register api.example.com to also use https.

I right now have to put a CloudFront in front of my EC2 instance just so that I can use the ACM. This seems a little overkill since I don't need any of the caching benefits.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options:

- Use CloudFront with SSL certificate from Amazon which doesn't bring any benefits for API that won't benefit from caching
- Use Elastic Load Balancer with SSL certificate from Amazon. Load balancer will mantain HTTPS connection with client and communicate via HTTP with your EC2 server. You can follow this tutorial https://hackernoon.com/getting-a-free-ssl-certificate-on-aws-a-how-to-guide-6ef29e576d22
- Or you can set up your certificate at EC2 instance directly. Here is how to do this with Nginx for example https://www.digicert.com/csr-ssl-installation/nginx-openssl.htm

EDIT: I have just realized that you could probably also use AWS API Gateway to point to your EC2 server [API GateWay to server in ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46468251/api-gateway-to-server-in-ec2)